# Keyboard types only numbers while letters are typed like diamonds

Tags: keyboard, recovery-mode

In recovery mode's root shell; whenever I type a letter it appears on the screen like a diamond. You can seen an example 
[image: in this photo]

Numbers are working great. How can I make it write out English instead of diamonds so I can enter commands?

Comment: Is it that hard?

Comment: yes, you are screwed! one solution is to use an external recovery usb stick, to boot from.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the default language is not english.
It can be changed by booting with a usb stick and changing the config file to make english the default language. I do not remember what config file it is.